# Azure ML Pipeline prohibit file upload

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

When creating a Pipeline with Python SDK V2 for Azure ML all contents of my current working directory are uploaded. Can I blacklist some files being upload? E.g. I use `load_env(".env")` in order to read some credentials but I don't wan't it to be uploaded.

Directory content:

```
./src
    utilities.py           # contains helper function to get Azure credentials
.env                       # contains credentials
conda.yaml
script.py
```

A minimal pipeline example:

```py
import mldesigner
import mlflow
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
from azure.ai.ml.dsl import pipeline

from src.utilities import get_credential

credential = get_credential()  # calls `load_env(".env") locally
ml_client = MLClient(
    credential=credential,
    subscription_id="foo",
    resource_group_name="bar",
    workspace_name="foofoo",
)


@mldesigner.command_component(
    name="testcomponent",
    display_name="Test Component",
    description="Test Component description.",
    environment=dict(
        conda_file="./conda.yaml",
        image="mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/openmpi4.1.0-ubuntu20.04",
    ),
)
def test_component():
    mlflow.log_metric("metric", 0)


cluster_name = "foobar"


@pipeline(default_compute=cluster_name)
def pipe():
    test_component()


pipeline_job = pipe()

pipeline_job = ml_client.jobs.create_or_update(
    pipeline_job, experiment_name="pipeline_samples"
)
```

After running `python script.py` the pipeline job is created and runs in Azure ML. If I have a look at the Pipeline in Azure ML UI and inspect *Test Component* and the tab *Code* I find all source files including `.env`.

How can I prevent uploading this file using the SDK while creating a pipeline job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a `.gitignore` or `.amlignore` file in your working directory to specify files and directories to ignore. These files will not be included when you run the pipeline by default.

Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/v1/how-to-create-machine-learning-pipelines#submit-the-pipeline) to prevent unnecessary files.

or

```
# Get all files in the current working directory
all_files = os.listdir()
# Remove ".env" file from the list of files
all_files.remove(".env")

@pipeline(default_compute=cluster_name, files=all_files)
def pipe():
    test_component()


pipeline_job = pipe()

pipeline_job = ml_client.jobs.create_or_update(
    pipeline_job, experiment_name="pipeline_samples"
)
```